# How can I use a xib with auto layout in iCarousel?

Tags: ios, autolayout, frame

I have an iCarousel set up to reuse a certain xib. This xib is using AutoLayout (as I am in the rest of my project). Apparently iCarousel does not use AutoLayout, and it does not work correctly with it. The view's constraints appear to be calculated for another frame, and then the view seems to resize...

I have an example project showing my setup [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ann5plhe2wjbzt6/iCarousel.zip?dl=0)

Here are some images of my troubles:
The first view is correct:
[image: good]

The second and all the others screw up in another way:
[image]